# IndexError when looping through rows in list

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I'm learning to write a simple script to read a CSV file to a list and make some edits.

The problem is with line 16. I'm confused as to why `Print row[1]` works and prints the second column to screen, but still throws an error.

Thanks very much!

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import sys

f1 = open(sys.argv[1], "rb") # opens the csv file to read

reader = csv.reader(f1)
myList = list(reader)
myList = myList[6:]

for row in myList:
    print row[1]
    del row[1]

f1.close()
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    print row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: print the content of `row` and check if indeed index `1` exists. Out of range error happens when you try to access an array index that does not exist.

Comment: what's the delimiter of your csv file? Since you forgot the specify it in `csv.reader`, all columns are accumulated in the first column of the row.

Comment: `print row` works without error. `print row[1]` prints the second column of all rows in my list, before giving me this IndexError.

Comment: The delimiter used is commas. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Sorry... I realised that the imported list contains an empty last row. Guess I need to sanitize the import.